# gem for uploading PDF template, fill the form and output the resulting PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I am looking for Gem in ruby on rails which simply upload those PDFs (form fillable fields) and have the system simply recall that PDF template, fill the form and output the resulting PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [iText library](http://itextpdf.com), which I successfully used in jRuby. It feels somewhat native when using it in jRuby. You'll certainly have to do some work, but I did exactly what you were after with iText.

Comment: Do you know any gem which fill fields for template pdf. I am using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: You can do this with iText! (Hence my answer.)

Comment: pdf-stamper gem works well for pdf forms filling. it requires JRuby.